# Prove that $f(x) = x^3$ and $g(x) = x^2|x|$ are not linearly dependant on the interval $[-1, 1]$

Tags: functions, linear-independence

It is hard to see how they can not be linearly dependant since depending on the value of $x$, $f(x)$ is either equal to $g(x)$ or $-g(x)$. Also, their wronskian ends up being zero as well.

I can see that $g(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, but I am not sure if it is enough to disqualify it from being linearly dependent. And even if they are not linearly dependent, would it then be right to call them linearly dependent?

Comment: If they are linearly deopndent, then  there is a constant $c$ such that $f(x)=cg(x)$ for all $x$. Can you arrive at  a contradiction?

Comment: Note: "Linearly independent" does not necessarily mean "unrelated."

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but anyway: $g$ _is_ differentiable at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\alpha f+\beta g=0$ on $[-1,1]$, for some scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$, Then, we have

$\alpha f(x)+\beta g(x)=0,~x \in [-1,1]$, implies $\alpha x^3+\beta x^2|x|=0$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$. In particular, $\alpha x^3+\beta x^2|x|=0$ for all $x \in [-1,0]$, gives $\alpha x^3-\beta x^3=0$ and thereby $\alpha-\beta=0$. Similarly, $\alpha x^3+\beta x^2|x|=0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, gives $\alpha x^3+\beta x^3=0$ and thereby $\alpha+\beta=0$. Finally, $\alpha=\beta=0$.